# Data frames using conditional probabilities to extract a certain range of values

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, distribution, sample

I would like some help answering the following question:

> Dr Barchan makes 600 independent recordings of Eric’s coordinates (X, Y, Z), selects the cases where X ∈ (0.45, 0.55), and draws a histogram of the Y values for these cases.
>
> By construction, these values of Y follow the conditional distribution of Y given X ∈ (0.45,0.55). Use your function sample3d to mimic this process and draw the resulting histogram. How many samples of Y are displayed in this histogram?
>
> We can argue that the conditional distribution of Y given X ∈ (0.45, 0.55) approximates the conditional distribution of Y given X = 0.5 — and this approximation is improved if we make the interval of X values smaller.
>
> Repeat the above simulations selecting cases where X ∈ (0.5 − δ, 0.5 + δ), using a suitably chosen δ and a large enough sample size to give a reliable picture of the conditional distribution of Y given X = 0.5.

I know for the first paragraph we want to have the values generated for x,y,z we got in `sample3d(600)` and then restrict the x's to being in the range 0.45-0.55, is there a way to code (maybe an if function) that would allow me to keep values of x in this range but discard all the x's from the 600 generated not in the range? Also does anyone have any hints for the conditional probability bit in the third paragraph.

```
sample3d = function(n)
{
  df = data.frame() 

  while(n>0)
  {
    X = runif(1,-1,1) 
    Y = runif(1,-1,1)
    Z = runif(1,-1,1)
    a = X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 

    if( a < 1 ) 

    {
      b = (X^2+Y^2+Z^2)^(0.5) 

      vector = data.frame(X = X/b, Y = Y/b, Z = Z/b) 
      df = rbind(vector,df)
      n = n- 1
    }
  }
  df
}
sample3d(n)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function produces a data frame. The part of the question that asks you to find those values in a data frame that are in a given range can be solved by filtering the data frame. Notice that you're looking for a closed interval (the values aren't included).

```
df <- sample3d(600)
df[df$X > 0.45 & df$X < 0.55,]
```

Pay attention to the comma.

You can use a dplyr solution as well, but don't use the helper `between()`, since it will look at an open interval (you need a closed interval).

```
filter(df, X > 0.45 & X < 0.55)
```

For the remainder of your assignment, see what you can figure out and if you run into a specific problem, stack overflow can help you.

Comment: You're welcome! If you'd like to upvote in addition to marking it the answer, you're now able to do that :)

Comment: How do you do that, sorry new to this page haha :)